# SQL cmd remote connection and database import

Tags: mysql, sql, cmd

I need to access an external database to import an sql file through windows cmd. My line is not working and I´m wondering what´s the problem since this must be the easiest way to do it. I want to do it this way becauseI´m told this would solve the problem of importing an sql database file that exceeds the limitation size and I don´t have access to the php.ini

```
mysql -u user -p pass --host=ip databaseName| file.sql
```

Comment: Are there any error messages printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the default behaviour of MySQL is not to permit remote access - you will have to get the owner to set this up (and modify their firewall as approprite).

I'm sure it is obvious, but I will say it anyway... you need to have MySQL installed on your machine, and I am pretty sure you will have to watch versions (I think there may be an extra switch to connect from a different version).